# Ruby length does not show the correct length of an array

Tags: ruby

I have a file with eight lines which is called quotes.txt. When I run the following code, it outputs an array with eight items and length of 1.

I am expecting 8 instead of 1. What am I doing wrong here?

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# myrandom_sig.rb

filename = ARGV[0] || (ENV['HOME'] + '/Documents/rubybyexample/RBE_scripts/quotes.txt')
quotation_file = File.new(filename, 'r')
file_lines = quotation_file.readlines()
quotation_file.close()
quotations     = file_lines.to_s.split("\n\n")
puts quotations
puts quotations.length
```

Outputs

```
➜  RBE_scripts  ruby -w myrandom_sig.rb quotes.txt 
["It is better to
have loved and lost than just to have lost.\n", "It is bad luck to be
superstitious.\n", "If it jams, force it. If it breaks, it needed
replacement anyway.\n", "Always remember that you are unique. Just
like everyone else.\n", "A woman without a man is like a fish without
a bicycle.\n", "A bachelor is a guy who is footloose and fiancee
free.\n", "If Yoda a great Jedi master he is, why not a good sentence
construct can he?\n", "People will remember you better if you always
wear the same outfit.\n"] 
1
```

Comment: Please paste the output of `puts quotations`

Answer (score 2):

This is the output of `quotations.inspect`:

```
["[\"Test\\n\", \"Line 2\\n\", \"Line 3 and some \\n\"]"]
```

The problem stems from you calling `file_lines.to_s.split("\n\n")`.  You are coercing the array to a string then back to an array.

Here's what you want to do:

```
filename = ARGV[0] || (ENV['HOME'] + '/Documents/rubybyexample/RBE_scripts/quotes.txt')
quotation_file = File.new(filename, 'r')
quotations = quotation_file.readlines()
quotation_file.close()
puts quotations.size
```

Comment: Given the code and the output that the OP has shown, I am not sure why the array reports an element of 1, when it looks like there's more than one element.

Comment: @MxyL I pasted the output of the inspect.  It was an array with **one** string in it that contained an array of strings; hence, size of 1.

Comment: That's interesting, since OP's output is an array with several strings. It seems as if the `puts` function is causing this confusion and makes it difficult to debug.